# Hibernate uses query twice file size when inserting/updating blob

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm using MySQL with Hibernate to save uploaded files in the database. The file is transformed into a byte array as a field of a simple entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TestBlob")
public class TestBlob {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "file")
    private byte[] file;

    public byte[] getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(byte[] file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

Then when I try to run the following code:

```java
    @Override
     public void addBlob(TestBlob t) {
      System.out.println("Trying to upload file with size:" + t.getFile().length);
      Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
      session.save(t);
    }

    @Override
     public void updateBlob(TestBlob t) {
      System.out.println("Trying to upload file with size:" + t.getFile().length);
      Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
      session.saveOrUpdate(t);
    }
```

I get this output:

```
Trying to upload file with size:8663040
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        TestBlob
        (file) 
    values
        (?)
...
com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (17326125 > 16777216).
```

The only relevant post I've found is [Loading 26MB text data from database consume JVM heap of 258MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680982/loading-26mb-text-data-from-database-consume-jvm-heap-of-258mb) or posts related to Postgre. Is there anything I can fix about my code or is it a some weird quirk that I need to know?

EDIT: I'm **required** to save files in a blob.

Comment: I think it would be better to put files out of the database and just put links to files in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Is there any way to insert a large value in a mysql DB without changing max_allowed_packet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754238/is-there-any-way-to-insert-a-large-value-in-a-mysql-db-without-changing-max-allo)

If you use Preparedstatement and there setBytes, then the Problem with doublesize is there, because of the Mysql-Driver behavior which doubles the size. Use setBinaryStream instead.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to configure your MySQL server to handle a larger packet size. See the following MySQL documentation for more information:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/packet-too-large.html